# I accidentally put my "Main.storyboard" stuff in my "Launch.storyboard" section

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

Is there a way I can quickly paste everything into "Main.storyboard"?

Comment: Rename Launch storyboard to Main

Comment: You can select all your ViewController and copy and paste them directly.

Answer (score 0):

select view controller copy and where to need pest it..

Answer (score 0):

You can just rename the storyboard, and then create a new, empty storyboard for your Launch.storyboard.

Another method is to drag a box around all the views etc you want and then copy and past into the other one.

Either will work.